# Kendo Grid for MVC displays 'no records found' message while fetching data, after upgrading Kendo UI to version 2020.1.406

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I downloaded the latest version of Kendo UI (Version: 2020.1.406) for MVC5 and upgraded my project to refer the latest JS, CSS and Kendo.MVC (2020.1.406.545). After upgrading, grid displays 'no record found' message even the record fetching is in progress.
Below is the image with Kendo UI (Version: 2020.1.406):
[image: kendo grid while fetching data]

It was working well with Kendo UI 2018.2.516 as below:
[image: kendo grid while fetching data]

I do not want to show 'No record found' message while fetching records, it should appear only after completion of fetching data and if no record exist.

Comment: I logged a ticket to Telerik technical support, they replied that it is a bug int the latest version 2020.1.406 of Kendo UI for MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since it is a bug in Kendo UI, do not use NoRecords method of grid. Instead use DataBound event and call below JS function:

function onGridDataBound(e) {
        if (!e.sender.dataSource.view().length) {
            var colspan = e.sender.thead.find("th:visible").length, emptyRow = 'No Record Found.';
            e.sender.tbody.parent().width(e.sender.thead.width()).end().html(emptyRow);
        }
    }